# What's the difference between () -> Unit and (Unit) -> Unit types?

Tags: kotlin

I have following functions:

```
fun <T, U> process(t: T, call: (U) -> Unit, map: (T) -> U) = call(map(t))

fun <T> processEmpty(t: T, call: () -> Unit) = process(t, call, {}) // error
```

but the `processEmpty` is not compiling. The error message is `Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> kotlin.Unit but (kotlin.Unit) -> kotlin.Unit was expected`. But if I change this function to

```
fun <T> processEmpty2(t: T, call: (Unit) -> Unit) = process(t, call, {}) // OK
```

So what's the difference between `() -> Unit` and `(Unit) -> Unit` types? Why first version of `processEmpty` isn't compiling?

Comment: I found, I think, better way to define `processEmpty` function: `fun <T> processEmpty(t: T, call: () -> Unit) = process(t, {call()}, {}) `

Comment: Yes, `{ call() }` is a correct function of one argument (implicit `it`), thus it can be passed as `(Unit) -> Unit`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) is actually a [type that has exactly one value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) (the value is `Unit` itself; also, this is why it is named `Unit`). It corresponds to `void` in Java, but it's not the same.

Kotlin compiler treats functions with no declared return value as [`Unit`-returning functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions), and `return Unit` can also be omitted. This is why `{ }` is a Unit-returning function.

But this is not applied to arguments. To be strict, when you declare a function with `Unit` argument or `(Unit) -> Unit` function variable, you have to pass an argument of type `Unit` at call site. The only value to pass is `Unit`.

A lambda with no specified arguments like `{ doSomething() }` is treated both as a function with no arguments and as a function with single implicit argument `it`. You can use `{ }` both as `() -> Unit` and `(Unit) -> Unit`.

As to the call site, as said above, `Unit` has to be passed:

```
val f: (Unit) -> Unit = { println("Hello") }

f(Unit) // the only valid call
```

Whereas `() -> Unit` functions do not need an argument to be passed:

```
val f: () -> Unit = { println("Hello") }

f() // valid call
```

---

In your example, type inference happens as follows:

```
fun <T, U> process(t: T, call: (U) -> Unit, map: (T) -> U) = call(map(t))

fun <T> processEmpty(t: T, call: () -> Unit) = process(t, call, {}) // error
```

1. `map: (T) -> U = { }`, thus a replacement for `U` is `Unit` returned from `{ }`.
2. Therefore `call` should be `(Unit) -> Unit`.
3. `call: () -> Unit` which is not the same to `(Unit) -> Unit`, as stated above. Error.